# Bootable SD Card doesn't appear at Startup Manager

Tags: mac, macos, startup, sd-card

I have a bootable SD Card with Windows 10 installed, and it works fine in the most of macbook pro I have tested, but there is one in which when I press alt / option key, the SD Card doesn't appears and I can not find the reason. Why it works fine in one but not work in another one?.

All the computers where I have tested are MBP retina display late 2013

Comment: Have you tested the SD card reader of the anomalous computer?

Comment: Yes, when the MBP is working, I connect the SD card to the card reader and it works perfectly. The problem is when I try to boot from it.

Comment: That's weird. Have you checked if Recovery's Disk Utility can see it?